# Set Icon in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, windows-7, icons

I want to replace the Tkinter icon with my own, but answers from other questions are not helping. In the same folder, I have my script and an image created using Paint saved as `icon.png`. Here is the script:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

icon = PhotoImage(file='icon.png')
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, icon)

root.mainloop()
```

This error is made from the root.tk.call method:

> TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "icon.png"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is actually in the line `icon = PhotoImage...`, above `root.tk.call...` - it attempts to read the file's data into a `PhotoImage` object and fails.

Tkinter does not natively support the PNG filetype. You need to use a supported filetype, such as GIF. If you want to choose from a wide variety of filetypes including PNG, I recommend installing [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/), the up-to-date fork of PIL ("Python Imaging Library"). However, it's probably easiest to just open the image in Paint again, save it as a GIF this time, and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for explaining things about file types. I saved it as a GIF and it worked, although I ended up using an embedded image with base64 because it is a small image.